# Update ios app every time more data is available on server

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have an app that needs to update every time a java web application creates more data. Simple enough, right?

But I found out that my app can`t run in background to ask for more data periodically, and I think I need to use the push notification system. That seems to be overly complicated for a really small thing.

And then, reading about it, I found out that the push notification can never arrive! For example, if the app is offline when the push notification is sent but is online a few moments later.

So, in that case, how can I update the data? I only bring data from the server when the user logs in. I didn't want to do that every time the application became active...

I guess there is a simple solution but this is my first app, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You only get data when the user logs in. But you don't want the user to login when the app is activated. And you want to get data in the background. Seems like contradictory desires. What is your actual goal (how often do users need to get updates, what iOS versions are you supporting)?

Comment: The user only logs in one time, after that the app is on the background logged until the iPhone is turned off or the user finishes the app. But I still need to show him new data, when the server creates it. I`m supporting iOS 5 and later versions

Comment: In what way are you showing the data then? And push notifications are not dependent upon the app being active, just that the app has registered to receive notifications (and the user permitted it).

Comment: The app shows documents created in another software. These documents can be created on any time, normally monthly. I need to create a way for my app to know about these new documents as soon as possible.

Comment: Surely you just want to notify the user that a new document exists. Then they can login to (download and) view it. That is what push notifications are for...

Comment: I know! But I was reading about it in this article http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 and the section "Push Notification Gotchas" scared me

Comment: Take it or leave it really. Neither you or Apple can deliver a notification if the device is off / has no connection to the world...

Comment: Sure, my only fear is never deliver the notification even if it becomes online moments later. Maybe today the user`s wifi is stuttering but tomorrow it will be ok. Then it needs to receive the message. Maybe I`m just doubting Apple reliability... Should I be doing that? haha :)

Answer (score 0):

You see why you should read your question before posting it?

> And then, reading about it, I found out that the push notification can
>   never arrive! For example, if the app is offline.
>
> So, in that case, how can I update the data?

Guess what, if you are offline, there is not much you can do... Moving on to serious things:

[iOS7 allows you to do periodic background fetchs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html) (check the **Multitasking Enhancements**). Have [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial) tutorial.

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't be clearer, let me explain: I send the push notification, right? The app RIGHT NOW is offline, so the notification never arrives. After some time, the app is back online and doesn`t have the new data.

Comment: And I can`t use an iOS 7 solution, because it needs to work in iOS 5. But thanks for the information :)

Comment: when the user get's inside the app, you download the data he needs, simple as that. Relying on APNS is not advised.

Comment: Are you saying the applicationDidBecomeActive method? I guess it's the way then. Thank you.